# How to change query sting to another string using PHP?

Tags: php

After successfully complete the registration form I am redirecting the user to **ccroipr-id.php?id=63** page. Here **a new value** is saved to the database which is

**ccroipr-201801101515569979**

this value is changed for every new registration.

Now, for every profile page, I am showing the data using **ccroipr-id.php?id=63** page.

But now I want the url will be

**ccroipr-201801101515569979.php**

So, desired possible outcome is: domain.com/ccroipr/201801101515569979

Can you tell me how can I achieve this?

Note: I am learning PHP.

Comment: you are using ajax request to create user or in PHP, means form submitted by ajax or php?

Comment: @SanjayKumarSingh Yes, the registration page is validating using jQuery/Ajax call. After successfully submitting the data I just redirecting to the ccroipr-id.php page.

Comment: have you tried using header('location: ccroipr-201801101515569979.php') or window.location.href?

Comment: @Suyog I know I can redirect them to `ccroipr-201801101515569979.php` page but the number is different for every registration.

Comment: so you can dynamically generate the file name every time.
e.g. $num = date('YmdHis');
$page = 'ccroipr-'.$num.'.php';
header('Location:'.$page);

Comment: @Suyog I want to use only one page e.g test.php for every `ccroipr-201801101515569979.php` page. This number will be different

Comment: @Suyog I don't want to create thousands of file.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed Would it suit you then to use an URL like `your-domain.net/profile.php/201801101515569979`, does it have to be `ccroipr-regtimestamp+rnd.php`?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer it will be better if it's `domain.com/ccroipr/201801101515569979`. Is it possible using .htaccess ?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I am showing the profile data using `ccroipr-id.php?id=63` now If got this url `domain.com/ccroipr/201801101515569979` then I can show the exact data because id `63` is for this column value: `201801101515569979`

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed So another user might get redirected to the page `ccroipr-id.php?id=65` instead, leading to another value, like `201801101515569999`?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yes you right, only the number will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the URL `domain.com/ccroipr/201801101515569979` for a user profile, you need to implement the following two steps:

**Create a php file called `ccroipr.php` on your site, that contains code to analyse the request's URL.**

This can be accomplished, by using the PHP global `$_SERVER` variable in PHP. It contains a field named `'REQUEST_URI'` that stores the path that was used to access the given file. So for the URL `domain.com/ccroipr/201801101515569979` the variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` holds the value `ccroipr/201801101515569979`. This can be used to extract the suer id:

```
$requestParts = explode('/', strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?', '?', TRUE));
$userId = '';
if (count($requestParts) > 1) {
    $userId = $requestParts[1];
}

if ($userId === '') {
    // Redirect to login page, generate a new ID or show an error.
    die();
}
// Call database and filter for the $userId value to retrieve all userspecific data
// Generate the specific HTML
```

The function `strstr($path, '?', TRUE)` cuts off all the GET parameters from the requested path. You can still access them through the `$_GET` variable though. A question mark is added to the original path to make sure the function still acts like expected in case no such parameters were submitted.

The function `explode('/', $url)` then separates all parts of the path that are separated by slashes, so each part can be analysed for itself.

The condition `if (count($requestParts) > 1)` checks, if the **path part** for the user id was submitted in the given URL. If it was, it is saved in the `$userId` variable. Keep in mind though, that there still might have been submitted an empty string for it. This will happen if someone calls `domain.com/ccroipr/` for example.

The condition `if ($userId === '')` then verifies, if a user id was really submitted.

**Modify your .htaccess file to allow requests that omit the .php ending.**

The way to accomplish that is best described in this question: [How to execute a PHP web page without the .php extension in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589075/how-to-execute-a-php-web-page-without-the-php-extension-in-the-url)

Comment: You can use `$dbValue = str_replace($'-', '/', $dbValue, 1);` to transform `ccroipr-201801101515569979` to `ccroipr/201801101515569979` or vary from the solution to explode the path with '-' chars instead of slashes. Keep in mind that you have to consider in the .htaccess file as well, if you want to do it.

Comment: Thanks for that dude but what happened if I access the site with `domain.com/ccroipr/` without the number?

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed The `$userId` variable would contain an empty string and therefore the condition `if ($userId === '')` would be true, resulting in an error, a redirect or anything else you program for that case.

Comment: Thank You, dude. I will apply that code and let you know If I am getting any issue but thanks for your help.